# Referencing a Prototype.js function from a function inside 'initialize'

Tags: javascript, function, prototypejs

In the following JavaScript code, from inside `function(elem) {...`, how do I reference the `reachMe` function ? I am just trying to attach a listener to `elem` so that `reachMe` gets called when `elem` gets clicked.

If I replace `whatHereToMeanTheReachMeFunction` with `this` it doesn't work because there `this` is the `window` object. If instead I put `reachMe` there I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindAsEventListener' of undefined*.

```
var MyClass = Class.create();

MyClass.prototype = {

    initialize : function(spec) {

        $$('*[id^=prefix]').each(

            function(elem) {

                elem.observe('click', whatHereToMeanTheReachMeFunction.bindAsEventListener(this));
            }
        );
    },

    reachMe : function(event) {

        console.log("Here I am.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few tweaks to your code and hopefully this will help you out

```
var MyClass = Class.create({
    //The class can be defined in one fell swoop
    initialize : function(spec) {
        $$('*[id^=prefix]').each(

            function(elem) {

                //you should only need normal bind() here
                elem.observe('click',this.reachMe.bind(this));
            },this
            //include 'this' here to set the context inside the each method
         );

        //you could also do the above action like this, 1 observer vs multiple
        document.on('click','*[id^=prefix]',this.reachMe.bind(this));

    },

    reachMe : function(event) {

        console.log("Here I am.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem and taught me something. I wasn't able to make the alternative `document.on(...` version work, apparently `this.reachMe` is undefined there, but it might be because my code snippet is not a runnable example so maybe in my real code there is some difference. The `elem.observe(...` version worked though, and your addition of `,this` after the function definition is certainly key.